# "Burnside ring" of the natural numbers and algebraic K-theory

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-k-theory

The construction of the Burnside ring $A(G)$ of a group $G$ (usually, but not always, finite) is given by taking the Grothendieck group of the commutative semi-ring of isomorphism classes of finite $G$-sets, in which the addition is given by disjoint union and multiplication is given by cartesian products.

However, it seems to me that the same construction appears to work for monoids $M$, where we consider now sets with (left) $M$-action.

In particular, consider the case when $M = \Bbb N$ is the monoid of natural numbers. Then an $\Bbb N$-set $X$ whose underlying set is finite amounts to a set equipped with an endomorphism.

**Question 1** Has $A(\Bbb N)$ been computed? If so, how may it be described?

Consider the category $\text{End}_S$, consisting of pairs $(K,f)$ in which $K$ has the homotopy type of a finite complex and $f: K \to K$ is a self-map. This is a Waldhausen category. Let $K(\text{End}_S)$ denote its $K$-theory.

(It seems to me that there is a homomorphism $A(\Bbb N) \to K_0(\text{End}_S)$.)

**Question 2** What is the relationship, if any, between $A(\Bbb N)$ and (some sort of equivariant) stable homotopy?

More precisely, consider the category $C_{\Bbb N}$ consisting of pairs $(X,f)$ in which
$X$ is a finite set and $f$ is a self map of $X$. We consider the isomorphisms of such objects as the morphisms of $C_{\Bbb N}$. Then the classifying space (realized nerve) $|C_{\Bbb N}|$ is a topological monoid and we can form the group completion
$$
\Omega B|C_{\Bbb N}|\, .
$$

**Question 2'** does $\pi_0(\Omega B|C_{\Bbb N}|)$ coincide with $A(\Bbb N)$?  What is the homotopy type of $\Omega B|C_{\Bbb N}|$?

It seems that by considering finite set as a discrete space
there is a map
$$
\Omega B|C_{\Bbb N}|\to K(\text{End}_S)
$$

**Problem 3** Give a $K$-theoretic interpretation of the homotopy fiber of this map.

Comment: Your definition of a transitive monoid is nonstandard.  Cyclic is more usual.  It is not true that all actions decompose into a disjoint union of cyclic ones.  And I don't think the direct product of two cyclic ones does.  People have looked at the semiring with all finite M-sets and disjoint union and direct product

Comment: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10485-016-9477-4 may be relevant but there are other papers too

Comment: You do have that each M-set deconposes as a disjoint union of indecomposable ones but these are not transitive and even a finite monoid can have even infinitely many indecomposable actions.

Comment: You can make a definition without using transitive $G$-sets. Namely, consider the set $W$ of all isomorphism class of finite $G$-sets. Then take the abelian group generated by elements of $W$ with relators corresponding to $X+Y=Z$ if $Z$ is the disjoint union of $X$ and $Y$. This also inherits a ring structure induced by cartesian product.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg thanks.  I guess I will change the definition and use the one mentioned by Ycor

Comment: This was the definition I mentioned in my first comment for monoids.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg the paper you linked to shows that $A(\Bbb N)$ is isomorphic to $A(\Bbb Z)$ (provided that these authors are using the same definition as the one here. The latter has been studied. See for example https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/~sieben/lothar/burnside_ring_of_cyclic_group.pdf

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg The Dress-Siebeneicher paper apparently gives the statement that $A(\Bbb Z)$ can be viewed as being isomorphic to a dense subring of the ring of universal Witt vectors.

Comment: It's not hard to work out generators and relations for $A(\mathbb{Z})$. You can use a "shearing isomorphism" to express how to decompose a Cartesian product of cyclic finite $\mathbb{Z}$-sets as a disjoint union of cyclic finite $\mathbb{Z}$-sets, and this does almost all the work. I suspect the calculation has been done independently many times over. I'll email you a written account if you think it would be helpful.

Comment: Im not sure if the paper I linked is using exactly the same definition.  It sounds like they extend the category and then do some homotopy.  My guess is with your definition the case of natural numbers is more complex

Comment: @A.S. sure! ae9462@wayne.edu

Comment: I suspect with your definition N is different than Z

Comment: After your edit: you probably need finiteness of the $G$-sets (or assume they're finitely generated $G$-sets i.e. existence of a finite subset $F$ such that $X=GF$). Otherwise taking any $X$, and defining $Y$ as the disjoint union of infinitely many copies of $X$, one gets $X=0$ in the "Grothendieck group". For instance, the Grothendieck group of the monoid of countable $G$-sets with disjoint union is zero.

Comment: @YCor,  yes, that was a mere oversight.

Answer (score 8):

$\DeclareMathOperator\im{im}$This is far from a complete answer, but too long for a comment. Specifically, I'll adress the beginning of 2', and the question of the relation between $A(\mathbb N)$ and $A(\mathbb Z)$ that was raised in the comments.

In both cases I'm assuming that your definition of $A(M)$ is about *finite* $M$-sets, and not arbitrary $M$-sets (whatever that would mean).

2' : The $\pi_0$ of a group completion is always the (ordinary) group completion of $\pi_0$ by some abstract nonsense with adjoints, so $\pi_0 (\lvert C_\mathbb N\rvert^\text{grp}) \cong (\pi_0\lvert C_\mathbb N\rvert)^\text{grp}$, and $\pi_0\lvert C_\mathbb N\rvert$ is exactly the semi-ring that you're using to define $A(\mathbb N)$, so they do coincide.

For the relation between $A(\mathbb Z)$ and $A(\mathbb N)$, note that there is an obvious "inclusion" map $A(\mathbb Z)\to A(\mathbb N)$. In fact, it is really an inclusion because it has a retraction $A(\mathbb N)\to A(\mathbb Z)$, which sends a finite set with endomorphism $(X,f)$ to the essential image $\im_\infty(f)$ with the induced endomorphism $f_\infty$. This essential image is $\bigcap_n f^n(X)$ which is clearly stable under $f$, and on which $f$ is surjective, so (by finiteness) bijective.

The construction $(X,f)\mapsto (\im_\infty(f),f_\infty)$ is functorial, in particular it is so when restricting to isomorphisms. Furthermore, it preserves disjoint unions and cartesian products so it induces a map of semi-($E_\infty$-)ring $E_\infty$ spaces $\lvert C_\mathbb N\rvert\to \lvert C_\mathbb Z\rvert$ and so a retraction of rings $A(\mathbb N)\to A(\mathbb Z)$ (but also of commutative ring spectra before passing to $\pi_0$).

However, $A(\mathbb Z)\to A(\mathbb N)$ is not an isomorphism. Indeed, consider the following group map $A(\mathbb N)\to \mathbb Z$, defined by sending $(X,f)$ to the cardinal of $X\setminus \im_\infty(f)$. Because $\im_\infty(f)$ preserves disjoint unions, this sends disjoint unions to sums and it sends an automorphism $f$ to $0$, however it is not $0$ on all $A(\mathbb N)$.

(If you take "THH" of finite sets instead of $K$-theory of finite sets with endomorphisms, $(\im_\infty(f),f_\infty)$ is all you can recover, cf. [my answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/406852/what-are-the-conjugacy-classes-of-the-category-of-kappa-small-sets/406926#406926) to [What are the conjugacy classes of the category of ($\kappa$-small) sets?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/406852/what-are-the-conjugacy-classes-of-the-category-of-kappa-small-sets), but this crucially uses cyclic invariance, so an identification of $(X,f\circ g)$ with $(Y, g\circ f)$.)

More generally, you have all the maps sending $X$ to the cardinal of $f^n(X)$ which are equal to the augmentation map on $A(\mathbb Z)$, but not on the whole of $A(\mathbb N)$. I would guess that the collection of these maps induces an injection $A(\mathbb N)\to A(\mathbb Z)\times \prod_\mathbb N\mathbb Z$, but that is just a guess.

Comment: Under your final map any two idempotent maps with the same cardinality image are equivalent but in fact they are not equivalent in A(N). The underlying additive group is A(N) is the free abelian group on all mappings whose essential range is a single cycle

Comment: Do we know that A(N) and A(Z) are not abstractly isomorphic (via some weird map)?

Comment: By the way I think of you map to The size of the essential range  of f -the size of f^n(X)  in the second coordinate you get an element of the direct sum of copies of $\mathbb Z$ which is cleaner.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg : yes to your first and last comments, and I don't know about your middle question

Comment: I'll add a post adding some extra info on the kernel of your map.  It has a natural interpretation.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg's [post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/419930) referenced [above](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/419872/burnside-ring-of-the-natural-numbers-and-algebraic-k-theory#comment1078398_419916).

Answer (score 6):

This is more an extended comment on @MaximeRamzi's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/4199163).  His comment reminded me of one of my favorite MO questions [Distinguishing combinatorial maps by their linearizations](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/198144/distinguishing-combinatorial-maps-by-their-linearizations) and it explains the kernel of his map. (See also the paper [Steinberg - Linear conjugacy](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/canadian-mathematical-bulletin/article/abs/linear-conjugacy/D3758252819C82CA0AEC99C44A5B0A27) inspired by this question which gives more details.)

If $M$ is a monoid, let $A(M)$ be the Burnside ring of $M$ (as defined in this post) and let $R(M)$ be the representation ring of $M$, that is, the Grothendieck ring of the semiring of isomorphism classes finite dimensional $\mathbb CM$-modules under direct sum and tensor product.  There is an obvious mapping $A(M)\to R(M)$ sending an $M$-set $X$ to the transformation module $\mathbb CX$. Note that cardinality induces a ring homomorphism $A(M)\to \mathbb Z$ and dimension induces a ring homomorphism $R(M)\to \mathbb Z$ and the map $A(M)\to R(M)$ is a homomorphism over $\mathbb Z$.

I claim that the kernel of the map proposed by @MaximeRamzi in his answer is exactly the kernel of the map $A(\mathbb N)\to R(\mathbb N)$.

Indeed, it is shown in [my answer to](https://mathoverflow.net/a/198148) the above-linked question using Fitting's decompositions and Brauer's lemma that two permutation matrices are conjugate as matrices iff they are conjugate as permutations, that if $f$, $g$ are maps on a finite set $X$, then the corresponding linear representations are equivalent iff the essential ranges of $f$ and $g$ are equal in $A(\mathbb Z)$ (i.e., have the same cardinality and cycle structure) and $\lvert f^n(X)\rvert=\lvert g^n(X)\rvert$ for all $n\geq 1$.  It follows immediately from this that the kernel of the map $A(\mathbb N)\to R(\mathbb N)$ is generated by all $[f]-[g]$ where $f$, $g$ are maps on the sets of the same cardinality with the same cardinality and cycle structure essential ranges and the images of $f^n$ and $g^n$ have the same cardinality for all $n\geq 1$.  But this is the kernel of the map at the end of @MaximeRamzi's answer.

**Added further commment**

There is a different ring you could associate to a monoid that is the $M$-set analogue of doing $G_0$ instead of $K_0$. For groups this gives the usual Burnside ring but for monoids it is different.  I strongly suspect this is what is done in the paper [Erdal and Ünlü - Semigroup Actions on Sets and the Burnside Ring](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10485-016-9477-4) I linked to in the [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/419872/burnside-ring-of-the-natural-numbers-and-algebraic-k-theory#comment1078253_419872) but I don't know.

The idea is that in a $G$-set $X$ for a group $G$, if $Y\subseteq X$ is $G$-invariant, then so is $X\setminus Y$ and you can write $X=Y+X\setminus Y$ in the Burnside ring.  But this doesn't work for monoids. You can have noncomplemented invariant subsets.  So one work around it to define quotient of $A(M)$ by the relations that if $Y$ is an $M$-invariant subset of $X$, then $[X] = [Y]+[X/Y]$.  But I think this doesn't quite work well because $X/Y$ is a pointed $M$-set.  So my feeling is that one should work in the category of pointed $M$-sets and that in the associated semiring, the action consisting of just a base point should be considered $0$. The product of pointed $M$-sets is the usual direct product  mod the invariant subset of points with one or more coordinate a base point.  The sum identifies base points.

For groups, a pointed $G$-set is basically the same thing as a $G$-set by adding a base point fixed by the group.

If we do this version of things for $\mathbb N$, then finite pointed $\mathbb N$-sets are partial maps on a finite set.  If you do the Grothendieck ring of the these things with pointed-direct sum and pointed direct product, you will get something complicated.  But if you factor by the relations $[X]=[Y]+[X/Y]$ for invariant $Y$, then you will get $A(\mathbb Z)\times \mathbb Z$ as an abelian group and the $\mathbb Z$ copy is a two-sided ideal, generated by the pointed set $A$ consisting of the base point and one other point that is mapped to the base point.  The product of a cycle with $n$ vertices (plus a base point thrown in) with $A$ is the sum of $n$ copies of $A$.

From the partial mapping view point this is the fact that  a strongly connected partial function digraph is either a single point with no edge or a cycle.